# CakePHP organising controllers

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i have the following queries common on few methods of the controllers. so is there a way to organise it ? i will need all the variables in the controller so i cant create a private method and return it.

```
    // Checks if the User is logged in if yes gathers the ID
    $id = $this->_loggedIN();

    // Find the ItemID from the Item Table
    $itemId = $this->User->Item->itemId('1', $id);

    // Finding the User Data and last Status Message
    $user = $this->User->Item->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Item.id' => $itemId), 'contain' => array('User', 'StatusMessage' => array('limit' => 1, 'order' => 'StatusMessage.created DESC'))));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a function in the AppController? Or even better - AppModel?

Comment: i can create it in the same controller. but i use $itemId and $user in other things below. u think i need to remove the $user find to a different method ?

Comment: Well, what would you like to organise here, then?

Comment: those three queries repeat 4 times in the same controller. like index() dishes() restaurant() photos()

Answer (score 2):

Since this seems to pertain to the logged in user, you should do this *once* and save the data in the session. If you're using the AuthComponent (which you probably should), there already is a generic way to find out whether a user is logged in and what his id is:

```
$this->Auth->user('id');
```

All the other data of the user model is accessible in the same way. This is simply stored in the session under the key `'Auth'` and is accessible like `$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')`. If you want to store even more data about the user in the session (like related items or whatnot), [do it once in the `login` method](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1274/autoRedirect).

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
}

function login() {
    if ($this->Auth->user()) {
        $item = /* find item */;
        $user = /* find user */;
        $this->Session->write('Auth.Item', $item);
        $this->Session->write('Auth.User', $user);
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    }
}
```